# hide zoom text on rangeSelector

Tags: highcharts

Does anyone know how to hide 'zoom' text on highstock's rangeSelector?
I already looked up the [API page](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector), but could't find the solution.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use lang options and set empty string.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang:{
            rangeSelectorZoom: ''
        }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q0ra5tk6/

Comment: Any idea where it is hidden for the version 6.1.0. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The **rangeSelectorZoom** property as suggested by Sebastian is not present in 6.1.0 anymore. A work around if you don't need the **From** and **To** Inputs, as it was my case is to not show the label at all:

```
rangeSelector: {
  labelStyle: {
     display: 'none'
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is already fixed in the master branch. Report: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8352

Comment: This is still relevant for version 9.1.2